# Failed to register with room server Webrtc in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc

I'm trying to make an app of video and audio call using `webrtc` in ios. I have followed [tutorials from here](https://cocoapods.org/pods/AppRTC)

When I run my app I get this error in my console.

> Failed to register with room server. Result:0.

I'm confused that why it is showing that and how will the opponent will show on my screen. I have mad remote View and local view also. This is my code for the video chat.

```
/* Initializes the ARDAppClient with the delegate assignment */
self.client = [[ARDAppClient alloc] initWithDelegate:self];

/* RTCEAGLVideoViewDelegate provides notifications on video frame dimensions */
[self.remoteView setDelegate:self];
[self.localView setDelegate:self];

[self.client setServerHostUrl:@"https://apprtc.appspot.com"];
[self.client connectToRoomWithId:@"512415354" options:nil];

- (void)appClient:(ARDAppClient *)client didChangeState:(ARDAppClientState)state {
switch (state) {
    case kARDAppClientStateConnected:
        NSLog(@"Client connected.");
        break;
    case kARDAppClientStateConnecting:
        NSLog(@"Client connecting.");
        break;
    case kARDAppClientStateDisconnected:
        NSLog(@"Client disconnected.");
        [self remoteDisconnected];
        break;
}
}

- (void)appClient:(ARDAppClient *)client didReceiveLocalVideoTrack:(RTCVideoTrack *)localVideoTrack {
self.localVideoTrack = localVideoTrack;
[self.localVideoTrack addRenderer:self.localView];
}

- (void)appClient:(ARDAppClient *)client didReceiveRemoteVideoTrack:(RTCVideoTrack *)remoteVideoTrack {
self.remoteVideoTrack = remoteVideoTrack;
[self.remoteVideoTrack addRenderer:self.remoteView];
}

- (void)appClient:(ARDAppClient *)client didError:(NSError *)error {
/* Handle the error */
NSLog(@"Error");
}

- (void)videoView:(RTCEAGLVideoView *)videoView didChangeVideoSize:(CGSize)size {
/* resize self.localView or self.remoteView based on the size returned */
}

- (void)remoteDisconnected {
if (self.remoteVideoTrack) [self.remoteVideoTrack removeRenderer:self.remoteView];
self.remoteVideoTrack = nil;
[self.remoteView renderFrame:nil];
[self videoView:self.localView didChangeVideoSize:self.localVideoSize];

}
```

Comment: u know anything about this issue? @onlyphantom

Comment: Try using a unique room name, like ham123za.
Sometimes if the room number you are using is already being used by some one in session then you can get this error. 
Best practice is to use room_number = username+timestamp (as timestamp and username are unique)